# Python tic tac toe winner determination

Tags: python

I am making a tic tac toe game in `python` as part of my college course. The board size is to be determined by the user, so could be 3x3 or 15x15, that depends on the users choice. Is there a way to determine in a few lines of code whether there are three entries in a row, irrelevant of what size the grid is or do I have to hard code in the winning combinations like:

```
if grid[1][1] == grid[2][1] == grid [3][1]:
    return True
```

For every possible line and combination in a larger board?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you implement it on event? I mean when a user enters a new point, just check if he won at that moment, and you won't have to check all the grid.

Comment: Also allow me to say that if in any grid that is bigger than 3x3 the winning condition is to make 3 in a row, the starting player will win 100% of the time.

Comment: I haven't gone over how to do that in college, could you show me an example of what you mean by implement it on event? And I know it's a bit silly but they're the specifications given to us by the lecturer! Thanks

Comment: sure give me a few minutes

Comment: Remember to accept the best answer and upvote the ones that you like or the ones that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

As @SiGm4 pointed out in the comments, if you check on each change by the user, you only have to check the possible winning combinations that contain the changed field. If you want to check all possible combinations, I suggest you use a `numpy` array that supports easy slicing. Checking then would be something like:

```
if np.any(np.logical_and(grid[ :-2, :] == grid[1:-1, :],
                         grid[1:-1, :] == grid[2:  , :])):
    return True # There are three consecutive matches horizontally
```

You then have to repeat that for vertical and both diagonal directions, which leaves you with 4 if clauses in total.

If it turns out that you want more in a row/column this gets unfeasible. Here you could something like filling the grid with 1's for one player and -1's for the other and then check, whether the moving window sum of a window of size N is N for a win of player 1 and -N for a win of player 2.

Comment: Can this be extended to N objects in a row?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins If you want to do it exactly like that, you would have to add additional `logical_and`'s.

Comment: I see, you mean to generate the logical_and objects in a loop and then pass them as a list?

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Atm This just checks neighbors. So if the first is same as the second and the second is the same as the third and connects them via and. For N objects in a row you would need 1. and 2., 2. and 3. ... and N. and connect them all via `logical_and`'s. If you want to have something that long. You should probably turn to something else like filling with 1's and -1's and then doing a rolling sum over N elements and compare those with N and -N.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really related to Python, it is basically discrete mathematics. Thus, there will be no magic advantage to using Python over C or Fortran or PHP or ..blank..

If I was you I would do the following

1. Store numbers 0,1 or 2 in a 2D array of length N (representing empty, cross or circle)
2. Design a function that extracts a 1D array of a diagonal given the 2D array and the diagonal index (there are 2n-1 total diagonals of each kind)
3. Design a function that given a 1D array determines if there are M consecutive numbers that are not 0. This can be done in O(N) by counting repeating numbers and restarting count if a different number appears
4. Use this function for all rows, all columns and all extracted diagonals of both kinds.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a very simple mock-up. Don't forget it is your job to finish your homework.

```
def printgrid(grid):
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        print (grid[i])

size = int(input("Give me size "))
grid= []
for i in range(size):
    line = []
    for j in range(size):
        line.append('')
    grid.append(line)
printgrid(grid)

while(1): #you need to put here a flag to end the game
    row = int(input("Give row "))
    col = int(input("Give col "))
    grid[row][col] = "X" #you need to make this for 2-players
    printgrid(grid)
    #check if vertical win (there are 3 diferrent vertical ones)
    #check if horizontal win (3 again)
    #check if first diagonical win (3 again)
    #check if second diagonical win (3 again)
```

The concept is that from the point that the new "X" was placed, there are only 12 different combinations that you have to check.

So if an "X" was placed in [4,4], for vertical you have to check the 3 following combinations:

```
1) [2,4],[3,4],[4,4]
2) [3,4],[4,4],[5,4]
3) [4,4],[5,4],[6,4]
```

Same for the other 3 directions

Comment: Thats great thank you @SiGm4 , I just wasn't sure how to approach it and get into it. Thanks for your perspective!